# Dynamically creating a form and creating scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

With AngularJs I'm trying to create a form dynamically that uses ng-model but I keep getting an error : **Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'eb_app-name' is non-assignable**. When I say dynamically I mean that only the form tags exist when the page is loaded and the input elements are added via user interaction.

I have the basics of the form already on the page.

```
<form class="form" method="post">
  <ul id="template" droppable></ul>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create Template</button>
</form>
```

I've omitted some attributes for brevity.

Using Drag and Drop form inputs are dropped onto the page and get added to the UL tag.

```
<div class='input-group'>
    <span class='input-group-addon' id='eb_app-name'>Name:</span>
    <input type='text' ng-model="eb_app-name">
</div>
```

Again some attributes have been removed.

The Drag and Drop process does not simply move a box from one place to another, when a Drop happens a new element is added to the DOM (the HTML above) using this code:

```
angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function ($compile) {

  var obj = $("#template");
  var objScope = obj.scope();

  obj.append(SOMEHTML);

  $compile(obj.contents())(objScope);
  objScope.$digest();
});
```

The last two lines are because SOMEHTML contains an ng-include that I need to be actioned. Full file is here : https://github.com/githublemming/cloudprovisioning/blob/master/public/controllers/template_add.js

Now I'm new to Angular and I believe this error is because the value in ng-model (eb_app-name) has not been declared already in the Controller for the scope.

Due to the nature of the application new 'widgets' could get defined and added at any time to the project and I don't want to hard code possible form variables and keep updating the controller when I create a new widget. What I would like to do is programatically declare the form variables when a widget is added to the page.

I've tried doing `scope[XXX] = ""` but I get the error when the `objScope.$digest();` line is called.

How can I do this? The full code can be found here : https://github.com/githublemming/cloudprovisioning if that makes things easier.

Thanks